# How to pass Custom Class ArrayList to another another Activity using Intent?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-intent

I have two Activities and I want to pass Custom Model Class ArrayList to another Activity, How can I achieve that?

In **Activity A**, I pass Array using this code :-

```
ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
someBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("dataList", arrayList);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the **dataList** in **Activity B** using intent.

Do share the solution how can I get the **dataList** in **Activity B**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Activity B within the `onCreate()` use the method `getIntent()` and check it has the data

Example Method:

```
Public boolean getExtraData(Intent intent){
   if(intent.hasExtra("dataList")){
      this.dataList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("dataList");
   }
}
```

See Also: Intent.java

```
/**
 * Retrieve extended data from the intent.
 *
 * @param name The name of the desired item.
 *
 * @return the value of an item previously added with
 * putParcelableArrayListExtra(), or null if no
 * ArrayList<Parcelable> value was found.
 *
 * @see #putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList)
 */
public @Nullable <T extends Parcelable> ArrayList<T> getParcelableArrayListExtra(String name) {
    return mExtras == null ? null : mExtras.<T>getParcelableArrayList(name);
}
```

Comment: As in your solution you used a Method intent.getExtra(), Their is no method like this and the similar method intent.getExtras() doesn't contain any parameter.

Comment: Sorry it was just an example you would need to use `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` and i will edit the answer

Comment: Thank You Sir, It worked I just have to implement Parcelable in my Custom Model Class.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the correct answer to help others if they find the question.